# I want to combine both result into one in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5

I just tried to following code in this fetch form have some result and fetchformans have another result but i want both into one result. I have tried many times but not get both result into one.

```
$fetchform = DB::table('create_form')->where('f_id','=',$id)->get();
$uid=session()->get('uid');
$fetchformans = DB::table('submit_forms')->where([['f_id','=',$id],['t_id','=',$uid]])->get();
```

Comment: did you mean you want to join query.

Comment: yes @Rahul Shrivastava